# 404 error when calling php

Tags: 404-error

```
                <html>
                <body>
                ***<form action="abc.php" method="post">
                    First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
                    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname"<br>
                    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
                <input type="submit">
                </form>
                </body>
                </html>***

        </div>
```

Using page.php as the template, I added a simple html form with a call to a php file (added html code is bolded and italicized above). The form displays perfectly. However, on pressing submit I get a 404 because it can't locate "abc.php". The URL generating the 404 is: "https://www.example.com/index.php/phpinserttest/abc.php". All files are are in the ../themes directory. Any ideas here ?

Comment: Context: page.php is of course the wordpress page.php. Probably obvious but I notice I left it out.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/abc.php">
```

I am assuming that abc.php is located in theme folder.

Comment: Yes abc.php is in the theme folder and the form modification you suggested worked. Thank You.